# No provisioning profiles have been detected. Please visit the iOS Provisioning Portal

Tags: xcode, xamarin, provisioning-profile

I just got a new OSX machine and decided to start fresh.

Setting up everything went relatively straight forwards (Xcode, Xamarin, Calabash...). However, when it came to the provisioning profile I got the following error:

> No provisioning profiles have been detected. Please visit the iOS Provisioning Portal at https://developer.apple.com to create one.Build: 1 error, 0 warnings

I somehow tend to always have problems when it comes to provisioning profiles... What I did:

1. Created new certificates
2. Created new provisioning profiles
3. Download provisioning profiles and double click on them
4. Add them in Xcode-> Devices -> (right click on device)Show Provisioning Profiles...

Needless to say the problem is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer on Xamarin's website, in case other people have the same problem and got here follow this [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/).

Reason:

> WARNING: Because of changes that Apple recently made to the way
>   provisioning works, Xamarin Studio currently is unable to refresh
>   changes or additions to iOS Provisioning profiles directly.

Solution from Xamarin website:
[image]